# POST-запрос через POSTMAN

Tags: post, postman

Товарищи, как понять данный текст? Пробую разными способами сделать запрос, а все равно ловлю 415 ошибку:

Сделайте POST запрос с помощью утилиты Postman. Вам нужно отправить запрос на адрес https://funkyb.ru/api/stage2 параметр secret, найденный на шаге 4 передается в строке запроса (query string), в теле запроса передается JSON с полем special со значением data-value, найденным на шаге 5

secret = 2021
special = 55

Comment: HTTP 415 - Неподдерживаемый тип данных. У тела запроса попробуйте тип данных поменять

Comment: Использование переменных и Flow?